# How do I prevent the text from wrapping in a alert dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I'm showing a very simple `AlertDialog` using this little snippet of code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder bldBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WarningActivity.this);
bldBuilder.setMessage(strTrace).setTitle(strTrace.split("\n")[0]);
AlertDialog dlgTrace = bldBuilder.create();
dlgTrace.show();
```

The content of my dialog is a stack trace and therefore the lines can be quite long. I'd like the prevent the wrapping of lines in the default alert dialog but I can't seem to figure out how. I've been trying to dig up this answer but I haven't been able to understand how.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to use your own `TextView` wrapped in a `HorizontalScrollView`, rather than `setMessage()`.

Comment: u want it in separate lines or a HozinzontalScroll is fine?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 possible options: First is to create your own layout. Second is to modify the default AlertDialog layouts' textview

```
//after creating the dialog, get the textview
TextView textView = (TextView) dlgTrace.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

//then set single line to false
textView.setSingleLine(false);
```